# How to map PascalCasing schema field to TRI Model Property

Tags: dxa

Usually we recommend to use camelCasing for field XMLNames during Schema creation. However sometimes we see the opposite.

I have a field in schema that using PascalCasing in XML Name `Description` and I am trying to map it to Model Property with TRI v1.0.1. Based on documentation I was hoping to achieve it with explicit semantic mapping like this:

```
[SemanticEntity(Vocab = "http://schema.org", EntityName = "Product", Prefix = "s", Public = true)]
public class Product : EntityBase
{
...
[SemanticProperty("s:Description")]
public string Description { get; set; }
...
}
```

However it did not work for me. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: what `SemanticEntity` annotation is added to the class where this property is part of? Could you edit your question and add the source code of the class too, so we know what vocabulary is meant by the prefix "s"?

Comment: Added source code of the class too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried using PascalCasing Schema fields myself, so not 100% sure if that will work. But since the standard in STRI is using camelCasing, I think it makes sense to stick to that standard, mixing the two is confusing to everybody wouldn't you say?

However looking at your annotation what is happening is the following:

1. you annotate with the prefix "s", so I'm assuming there is a `SemanticEntity` annotated on the class with a vocabulary defined, most likely that is "http://schema.org"
2. this means your Schema will need to be annotated with that vocabulary too, and the field will need to be annotated with the mentioned property as described in the [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-7EA7470E-1592-4734-B824-8F23FF3BD526)

However, I think you will be able to test this quicker if you just follow the process of mapping an `Entity` field to a Schema field with a different name.

So for example, if your Schema field was named "headline", you would use the following in your `Entity` class:

```
public string Headline { get; set; }
```

But if you wanted your `Entity` field to be named `Subtitle` for instance, you would then annotate it like this:

```
[SemanticProperty("headline")]
public string Subtitle { get; set; }
```

Now if I understand corrrectly, you have a Schema field `Description`, so I would suggest to simply try:

```
[SemanticProperty("Description")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

If that doesn't work, then you can go the route of Semantic mapping via a vocabulary (which means using prefixes), but then don't use schema.org, since that does not have a field `Description`. You will have to use a custom vocabulary (you can simply use `http://stan.org`). Make sure you follow the [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-7EA7470E-1592-4734-B824-8F23FF3BD526) to map that vocabulary correctly on the Schema and annotate the field, and then don't forget to republish the settings (because else this new Schema mapping isn't known by the web application).

Comment: +1 to stan.org for Stan projects. Otherwise an organization can help make it clear _who_ put in the mapping. :-)

Comment: @AlvinReyes I would indeed suggest to use the customer name for their custom vocabulary, or use a public vocabulary if available and when it makes sense ;o).

Comment: Would the `schema.org` specification itself count as a vocabulary? I'm curious about other examples of a *public vocabulary*.

Comment: @BartKoopman Does it mean that every time when we specify SemanticEntity attribute on our model, we also have to specify semantics on Schemas in CM?

Comment: @Stan not really, semantic mapping is done via the Schema, so you can map against what is specified on the Schema rather than using the Schema field names. But specifying a public `SemanticEntity` on the Entity class, can also be done without anything set on the Schema. I would say it makes sense to use both these features at the same time, but in your situation, you shouldn;t need semantic mapping via a vocabulary I think.

Comment: Got it! Looks like I need to play more with it :) One more question - documentation says that by applying semantic annotations on schemas we can map existing Schemas to existing View Models without changing the View Model semantics. Does it mean that we can create semantic mapping on schemas/fields in CM and leave View Model without any `SemanticEntity` and `SemanticProperty` attributes?

Comment: @StanKroshchenko not really (that sentence is perhaps a bit too broad and might be misleading), that is still assuming that the model class already has semantics set on it. So looking at the [Article model](https://github.com/bkoopman/tri/blob/master/web-application/Sdl.Web.Common/Models/Entity/Article.cs), you could create a new Schema Blogpost, and map that to the Article model using the schema.org semantics.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you're seeing the [default semantics](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-2BED2168-26D2-465E-92D8-68C3D5219088) when not "annotating" the view model:

> When attempting to populate a View Model property from the Content Manager model, look for a Schema field with the same name, but using
>   camelCasing instead of PascalCasing. For example, the property
>   Headline is mapped to Schema field headline.

We annotate the Schemas with AppData (not visible in the CME). [See part three of the docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-7EA7470E-1592-4734-B824-8F23FF3BD526), where it describes field mappings with a PascalCasing convention, done inline in the the Schema source (e.g. `name="TextField"` in the example).

I played with Bart Koopman's TridionWorld custom page to change these, see the source at:
https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/AppData%20Custom%20Page/trunk.

Placing these under the CME (in IIS and matching folders) to browse and change the AppData in a GUI. For example I have the AppData extension files in:

`%TRIDION_HOME%\web\CustomPage\AppData\`

And in IIS:

`SDL Tridion\CustomPage\AppData` *Where CustomPage is a folder and AppData is an application.*

<strike>Someone else can confirm (Bart), but I believe</strike> The custom vocabularies (annotations) go in the left and Schema mappings go on the right (note the URL `[CME URL]/CustomPage/AppData/`):

[image: Custom AppData Page]

**Edit**: clarified field-level annotation is in the Schema source (.xsd) based on Bart's comment.

Comment: Schema annotation is appdata, field annotation is done inline the XSD, see the Article Schema for an example. When adding custom vocabularies, indeed, you add the vocabulary on the left in the custom page (under vocabularies) and define a certain prefix for it. You can then map a Schema to a type of that vocabulary on the right via the Schema mapping, using `<typeof>prefix:type</typeof>`

Comment: Semantic annotation on Schema and Schema fields are applied when we don't want to modify View Model in Web Application. In my case I want to control all mappings in Web App.

Comment: Makes sense, especially if we wanted an STRI delivery setup against existing Schemas and content. I guess the next question is if we currently can't set these, what parts can we change versus what's a "product" request/issue (the repository's [issues list is on GitHub](https://github.com/bkoopman/tri/issues)).

Answer (score 1):

Based on Bart's answer I made it work by removing prefix from `SemanticProperty` attribute.

```
[SemanticEntity(Vocab = "http://schema.org", EntityName = "Product", Prefix = "s", Public = true)]
public class Product : EntityBase
{
...
[SemanticProperty("Description")]
public string Description { get; set; }
...
}
```

It means that `SemanticProperty` attribute for explicit mapping does not work with prefixes - that can provide structured content markup. In order to achieve it Semantic Mapping on Schema/Schema fields must be used.

Comment: If you use prefixes then your Vocab should match the Tridion schema namespace in order for the mapping to 'work'. As you say, alternatively you can also annotate your Tridion schemas with the schema.org semantics to drive the mapping. In your example above you could remove the schema.org semantics totally, or if you do want this in your rendered markup, add another [SemanticProperty("s:description")] annotation (as per http://schema.org/Product)